# Why is 'Authenticated' setup of FTP on ubuntu very insecure?

Tags: server, users, ftp, authentication

I am reading the documentation for setting up an FTP server on Ubuntu, and the documentation states that using Authenticated users is very insecure. I dont understand why, because I am under the impression that that I can allow specific users access and only those?

[Documentation link](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/ftp-server.html.en)

Comment: @Terrance The line i am referring to is: "In the Anonymous mode, remote clients can access the FTP server by using the default user account called "anonymous" or "ftp" and sending an email address as the password. In the Authenticated mode a user must have an account and a password. This latter choice is very insecure and should not be used except in special circumstances."

Comment: Ah yes, that can be insecure if you are on an open network like in a school, coffee house, etc.  Like what was posted below is that they are transferred in plain text.  Best to open a VPN first for something like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With FTP user name and password are transferred as plain text without encryption. An attacker may sniff them from the network and use them to log in.

It's the same problem as with e.g. telnet